# Report cannot be found

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I try to show `SSRS` Reports in asp.net web page. Everything seems fine but when I click on `button` and want to show reports then this shows

> The item '/Report Project1/Report1.rdl' cannot be found.
>   (rsItemNotFound)

but I Add report `project1` and also add `report1` here is code

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        ReportViewer2.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
        ReportViewer2.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://lenovo-pc/ReportServer");
        ReportViewer2.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/Report Project1/Report1.rdl";
        ReportViewer2.ServerReport.Refresh();
}
```

Is the path right or wrong?

Comment: Did you managed to find a solution um getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest taking the .rdl extension of of the path, I believe it is not needed if memory serves me correct.

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old question, but this answer is for those who still struggling to find the solution for it.

1. Check the path of your file in the report server
2. check  whether the folder name  is the same name as ur project name
3. If not change it to project name